# ubuntu 18.10 - filezilla GnuTLS

Tags: filezilla, gnutls

Filezilla version 3.33.0 using GnuTLS 3.6.4 suddenly and constantly throws an error GnuTLS-error -50 after trying to initialise TLS. No connection works.

Answer (score 3):

It was identified as a bug in Filezilla 3.33.0 the day after Ubuntu 18.10 was released.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bug/1798767

Apparently it was to be fixed in Filezilla 3.38.0, which was released on 2018-10-26, and quickly followed by version 3.38.1 on 2018-10-27, but these versions haven't yet made it to the Ubuntu repo to update the version available for users to install.

It was also recently raised on the Filezilla support forum with a work around mentioned there, however I couldn't get that to work on Kubuntu 18.10. Edit: my mistake, the work around does work on Kubuntu 18.10. It was KDE Neon 16.04 that I had trouble with.

See https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=50159

Answer (score 1):

Than k you for the info. as per December 10th, there is still no updated version in the repositories of ubuntu cosmic (filezilla-common_3.33.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem I have used Flatpak ==> [FileZilla on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla)

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in Filezilla 3.38.0. Thought the update is not available in ubuntu store. But you can download and install it manually here -
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client